# Wagtail asynchronous call to Page model method from JS

Tags: django, asynchronous, mixins, wagtail

I am trying to implement a lazy load of images in a Wagtail run website.

I am trying to use the RoutablePageMixin: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html

My Page model:

```
class Gallery(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    #I have removed all the code for readability

    @route(r'^gallery/loadImages/')
    def lazy_load_images(self, request):
        I want to hit this method with the JS call.
        pass


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Gallery"
```

My JS code:

```
(function($) {
  $('#lazyLoadLink').on('click', function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var page = link.data('page');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'gallery/loadImages/)',
      data: {
        'page': page,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN // from index.html
      },
      success: function(data) {
        debugger;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        debugger;
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

If I want I can reach all urls in the page model with @route(r'^$') but cannot make it reach the method from the url in the AJAX method.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What does the browser network panel say when you make the ajax request? Can you see the request being made and does the URL look correct? If so, what is the status code of the response you're getting back?

Comment: This is what it returns: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/loadImages/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I approached it as regular django with urls.py and views.py added to the wagtail app and works. Couldn't make it work with the RoutablePageMixin.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you're missing a leading `/` in your AJAX call url (and an extra `)` character?). Try changing the `url` to `/gallery/loadImages/`, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/gallery/loadImages/',
  data: {
    'page': page,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN // from index.html
  },
  success: function(data) {
    debugger;
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    debugger;
  }
});
```

As a side note, you want to consider adding a `$` character to the end of your route, so that it will only match `/gallery/loadImages/` *exactly*. Otherwise it will also match routes like `/gallery/loadImages/foobar`. I'd change it to: `@route(r'^gallery/loadImages/$')`.